# Laravel 8 - Old inputs and validation error messages are not working

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-blade, laravel-8

I am trying to display the error div below a certain field if the validation for that input failed along with the previous input on the designated field.

Here's my progress so far: 
in my **`controller`** file inside the **`store`** function **`(UserController > store)`**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $validationRules = array(
        'first_name' => 'required|min:2|max:150',
        'last_name' => 'required|min:2|max:150',
        'gender' => 'required',
        'birthdate' => 'required',
        'user_contact' => 'required|min:10|max:20',
        'email' => 'required|unique:users|max:150'
    );

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $validationRules);

    if($validator->fails()){
        //dd($validator)
        return redirect(route('user.create'))->withInput()->withErrors($validator);
    }

.....
```

When I try to print **`$validator`** using **`dd()`** it does not have any problem and it contains the **validation error messages, all inputs and validation rules**.

[image]

Here's my snippet code in the **`create.blade.php (view)`**:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method = "POST" action = "{{ route('user.store') }}">
        @csrf
            <div class="form-group row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <strong><font color="red">*</font> Indicates required fields.</strong>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_fname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">First Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_fname') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="first_name" 
                                name = "first_name"
                                value="{{ old('first_name') }}"
                                minlength="2"
                                maxlength="150"
                                required/>
                        @error('first_name')
                            <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('first_name') }} </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_lname" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Last Name <font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_lname') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="last_name" 
                                name = "last_name"
                                value="{{ old('last_name') }}"
                                minlength="2"
                                maxlength="150"
                                required/>
                        @error('last_name')
                            <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('last_name') }} </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_gender" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Gender <font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_gender') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-venus-mars"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <select class = "form-control" id = "gender" name = "gender" required>
                            <option value = "M">Male</option>
                            <option value = "F">Female</option>
                        </select>
                        @error('gender')
                            <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('gender') }} </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_birthdate" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Birth Date <font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_birthdate') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="far fa-calendar-alt"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="birthdate" 
                                name = "birthdate"
                                value="{{ old('birthdate') }}"
                                required/>
                        <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('birthdate') }} </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_contact" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">Contact Number <font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_contact') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-phone"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="user_contact" 
                                name = "user_contact"
                                value="{{ old('user_contact') }}"
                                onkeyup="this.value=this.value.replace(/[^\d]/,'')"
                                minlength="10"
                                maxlength="20"
                                required/>
                        @error('user_contact')
                            <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('user_contact') }} </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_email" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">E-Mail Address<font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_email') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-at"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="email" 
                                class="form-control" 
                                id="email" 
                                name = "email"
                                value="{{ old('email') }}"
                                minlength="10"
                                maxlength="150"
                                required/>
                        @error('email')
                            <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('email') }} </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <label for="u_utype" class="col-sm-6 col-form-label">User Type <font color="red">*</font></label>
                    <div class="input-group mb-2 {{$errors->has('u_utype') ? 'has-error' : ''}}" >
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                            <span class="input-group-text"><i class="fas fa-user-cog"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <select class = "form-control" id = "u_type_input" name = "u_type_input" required>
                            <option value = "E">Employee</option>
                            <option value = "A">Administrator</option>
                        </select>
                        @error('u_type_input')
                            <div class="alert-danger">{{$errors->first('u_type_input') }} </div>
                        @enderror
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default float-right" name = "submit_create" id = "submit_create">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </form>
```

Notice that I removed the **`autocomplete=off`** because I read some posts that this causes the problem but still doesn't work in my case.

I've been reading all stackoverflow posts related on my problem but most of the scenario problem occured on Laravel 5 and I use the current latest version of Laravel Framework which is Laravel 8.

> **What seems to be the cause of the problem?** and how should I retain the
> old/previous inputs and show the error messages after the failed
> validation? **I suspect that the cause of the problem lies on the blade**
> **file or related to the resources like bootstrap.**

Comment: I am not sure but try to redirect() like this `redirect()->route('user.create')->withInput()->withErrors($validator);`

Comment: @bhucho tried it but still the same

Comment: `you may use the withErrors method to flash the error messages to the session`, this is what is written in docs, then try to check the flash messages are in session, try to add `@php session()->all(); @endphp`, it will show if message is there in & with what key

Comment: thanks for the help @bhucho i can now print the values of flash with old and new keys but it shows empty (no keys and no values). it seems that this is a new problem and also a progress..

Comment: not understood, can you explain in detail

Answer (score 1):

you can try this to redirect

```
        if ($validator->fails())
        {
            return redirect()->back()->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }
```

and while showing into the blade file try this one

```
 @error('user_contact')
        <div style="color: red;">{{ $message }}</div>
 @enderror
```

Comment: It gives me this error: `ErrorException
Undefined variable: message (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\Inventory\resources\views\User\create.blade.php)` - `$message is undefined`

Comment: Can you make changes in controller also if yes add in your question?